# Coremltools: How to subtract mean value of image from input image?

Tags: average, normalization, mean, subtraction, coreml

I'm using swift to run my model, which is converted from keras, unfortunately, the result is extremely bad while running on swift, so I consider maybe something run with my preprocessing.  Then I find that coremltools can scale and subtract the input with a specific value like 255 and -1 in following code:

```
coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model,image_scale=255,red_bias=-1,green_bias=-1,blue_bias=-1)
```

However, if I need to subtract the average of the input image from image and do the normalization, what should I do ?
Should I use coremltools or swift?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is an easy way to do this, but Core ML models do support a "NeuralNetworkMeanImage" operation that subtracts a mean image from the input image. This is part of the "NeuralNetworkPreprocessing" part of your model.

When you use `image_scale`, `red_bias` etc, the NeuralNetworkPreprocessing uses the NeuralNetworkImageScaler operation. But you want to use the NeuralNetworkMeanImage operation instead.

It doesn't appear that `coremltools.converters.keras.convert()` lets you choose this mean image operation. So the solution would be to write a new script that loads your converted mlmodel and replaces the preprocessing operation with NeuralNetworkMeanImage. This requires familiarity with the protobuf format.